# Flume Output not showing in the terminal

Tags: telnet, flume, flume-ng

I am currently working with flume and i tried to work with basic examples.but the thing is whenever i tried to run flume agent not logs are showing
I followed many tutorials but all end up as same result

```
/usr/hadoop-env/flume-1.10.1/bin$ ./flume-ng agent -n na -c conf -f ../conf/flume-conf-netcat.properties>text.txt
```

This is the command i tried to run

```
na.sources = nas1
na.channels = nac1
na.sinks = nal1
na.sources.nas1.type = netcat
na.sources.nas1.bind = localhost
na.sources.nas1.port = 77777
na.channels.nac1.capacity = 100
na.channels.nac1.type = memory
na.sinks.nal1.type = logger
na.channels.nac1.capacity = 100
```

This the config file file.
i have tried many examples but all end up at this stage

Output is showing like this

```
Info: Including Hadoop libraries found via (/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop) for HDFS access
Info: Including Hive libraries found via () for Hive access
+ exec /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Xmx20m -cp 'conf:/usr/hadoop-env/flume-1.10.1/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/usr/local/hadoop/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/lib/*' -Djava.library.path=:/usr/local/hadoop/lib org.apache.flume.node.Application -n na -f ../conf/flume-conf-netcat.properties
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hadoop-env/flume-1.10.1/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.18.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

and noting is showing and i tried telnet but no output can someone help me.

Comment: There will be no output unless you send events to `localhost:77777`. Also, you have `>text.txt`, so either remove that, or go look at that file for the stdout

Comment: Check the port, they are from 1 to 65535. And you enter 77777 which can be interpreted by different software differently.